# "Application is not responding. Would you like to close it?" getting an error while running service in Android

Tags: android, android-service

I have an Android application that has a button that starts the service.

Here is the service:

```
public class SimpleService extends Service 
{
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service Started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();               
        Integer i=0;
        while (i<10)
        {
            Log.d("Hi",i.toString());   
            SystemClock.sleep(5000);                    
            i++;            
        }
        Log.d("Hi","return START_STICKY");      
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy() 
    {       
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service Stopped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();           

    }
}
```

When I clicked on the button, the service starts successfully, but after some while, in the emulator, I got an error like

> Application is not responding. Would you like to close it?

Am I doing anything wrong in service implementation?

What I want to do is perform a task on every 5 seconds even if my application got killed.

I tried with IntentService but it got killed when my app got killed so my task remains incomplete.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: At the time of creating class SimpleService did you make it as a subclass of Service?

Comment: @Rohan Sarkar i just extend Service class to create a service as mentioned above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     while (i<10)
    {
        Log.d("Hi",i.toString());   
        SystemClock.sleep(5000);                    
        i++;            
    }
```

I would like to point out this part of your code. Here what you are doing is once your service starts, you are doing 10 iterations of loop and in each iteration you are pausing execution for five seconds (which is a lot of time in terms of execution). As services run in the main process, in my opinion, they block the main thread, which means during the sleep, if your app is accessed, you will get the ANR (App not responding) error. Thus, these types of tasks should be run in a separate thread.

If you want to perform some repetitive tasks on the background, I'd suggest you make use of a AlarmManager component of the Android SDK.Alarm manager is a system service, thus you can access it by using the following line of code.

```
    AlarmManager mAlarmMgr=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
//Then you can set alarm using mAlarmMgr.set().
```

You will then receive the alarm in a AlarmReceiver.

> AlarmReciever class extends BroadcastReceiver and overrides onRecieve() method. inside onReceive() you can start an activity or service depending on your need like you can start an activity to vibrate phone or to ring the phone.

I hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: will it work if i killed my application ? my task must be keep performing even after app got killed. will BroadcastReceiver  achieve this ?

Comment: If you have registered an alarm receiver on your manifest and you schedule your alarm, your broadcast receiver will receive the alarm even if your app is not running. With that receiver, then you can start your Service to perfrom your task.

Comment: Please look at this article: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 0):

Since By Default, all your app components (like Activity, Service etc) runs in Main/UI Thread, and if it get blocked, Android shows ANR dialog.

Also, Each of lifecycle method of service is called from UI thread. If you need background task to be running all the time, you can crate new thread for this.

You may try below code inside your Service class:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {

    while(i<10)
    {
       Thread.sleep(5000) 
       //REST OF CODE HERE//
    }

 }
}).start();
```